# Java style reference returns in C++

Tags: java, c++, reference

Consider this Java code snippet:

```
Vertex a = graph.addVertex(null);
Vertex b = graph.addVertex(null);
```

Is it possible to do the same in C++? AFAIK only option in C++ would be:

```
Vertex& a = graph.addVertex(NULL);
```

Or maybe this:

```
typedef Vertex& Vertexref;
Vertexref a = graph.addVertex(NULL);
```

Of course returning a copy of the object is also possible.

But Java syntax seems more straightforward to me. Would it be possible to have it in C++?

Comment: You can modify the `Vertex` class to store shared pointers to its data, if you don't really care about performance.

Comment: Don't typedef a reference, or the people who have to maintain your code will hunt you down.

Comment: @Benjamin `shared_ptr` performance is pretty good, and usually good enough - especially since the compiler will elide many of the copies.

Comment: I do not intend to typedef a reference. I just wanted to make clear it is possible in order to have a syntax more similar to Java. I am aware of the drawbacks of doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may think the Java syntax is more straightforward, but have you tried returning a copy of an object in Java? That's far less straightforward. C++ makes you opt in to references, whereas Java makes you opt in to *not* references. Swings and roundabouts.

You have already shown us the two ways to write this in C++, and they are both very straightforward.

Comment: It also seems wrong to me. Sometimes I wonder why C++ doesn't provide a mechanism to return references without needing the caller to explicitly create a reference.

Comment: @jbgs: Are you saying, you wonder why C++ doesn't provide a mechanism for a variable that looks like a value of type `Vertex`, but if it was initialized using a call to `addVertex` is actually a reference to type `Vertex`? Aside from implementation difficulty, the reason is that this would be incredibly difficult to read. In C++ `Vertex a;` always declares a value (if `Vertex` is a class type). In Java `Vertex a;` always declares a reference. Why would you want a feature in *either* language to make it difficult to tell which you have? Explicitly stating the difference is *good*.

Comment: Why not? When you call a function there's no way to know if you are passing by reference or by value (unless you have a look at function's signature). Cannot we have the same issue for return values? I agree it might be inconvenient anyway.

Comment: Sure, let's take an inconvenience, and apply it somewhere else too. That's fun.

Answer (score 5):

Java objects are referenced by pointers, even if it's not visible in the syntax in the same way as in C++. Your Java function doesn't really return a reference (in the C++ sense, not just a synonym for pointer), but it returns a pointer, and that pointer is returned by value. So the equivalent C++ would be something like this:

```
Vertex* a = graph.addVertex(null);
Vertex* b = graph.addVertex(null);
```

It is a mistake to think of the "references" in Java as the same thing as the "references" in C++. The Java "references" are pointers. C++ "references" are aliases for variables, which is not the same thing as a pointer, even though they are usually (but not always) implemented "under the hood" using pointers.

To clarify: This is not just terminology nitpicking. Your C++ program will not behave the same as your Java program, if you just translate Java references to C++ references. To make an equivalent C++ program, you need to use pointers.